# Problem mapping a Many to MapObject to Many relationship in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have an aggregate root of an Administration.  The Administration object has a 1 to many relationship with Forms.  Forms has what is CLOSE to being a many to many relationship with Modules, however there is a property on the link, so I've created a mapping object named FormModule which has a property for a Sequence integer.

I've jiggered around with the Cascade & Inverse settings in the configuration, but I can't figure out the right combination that will allow me to save a new Administration object with all of its dependent objects.  I'm using a composite key on the FormModule table, but the KeyReference doesn't appear to have any means for me to set it to save the Modules, and I get the error

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: Module

Here's the code for the classes

```
public class Administration 
{        
    public virtual int AdministrationId { get; protected set; }

    protected IList<Form> _forms = new List<Form>();
    public virtual IList<Form> Forms
    {
        get { return _forms; }
    }                        
}

public class Form 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Administration AdminKey { get; protected set; }
    protected IList<FormModule> _formModules = new List<FormModule>();
    public virtual IList<FormModule> FormModules
    {
        get { return _formModules; }
    }
}

public class Module 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Administration AdminKey { get; protected set; }
    protected IList<FormModule> _formModules = new List<FormModule>();
    public virtual IList<FormModule> FormModules
    {
        get { return _formModules; }
    }
}

public class FormModule 
{       
    public virtual Form Form { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Module Module { get; protected set; }
    public virtual int Sequence { get; protected set; }        
}
```

And heres the code for the Fluent NHibernate config

```
public class AdministrationMap : ClassMap<Administratio>
{
    public AdministrationMap()
    {            
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("AdministrationId")
            .Not.Nullable()
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        HasMany(x => x.Forms)
            .KeyColumn("AdministrationId")                
            .Cascade.All();            
    }
}

public class FormMap : ClassMap<Form>
{
    public FormMap()
    {            
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("FormId")
            .Not.Nullable()
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        HasMany(x => x.FormModules)
         .Cascade.All()

        References(x => x.Administration).Column("AdministrationId").Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class ModuleMap : ClassMap<Module>
{
    public ModuleMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("ModuleId")
            .Not.Nullable()
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        HasMany(x => x.FormModules)
            .Cascade.All();
            //.Inverse()  //try this;

        References(x => x.Administration).Column("AdministrationId").Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class FormModuleMap : ClassMap<FormModule>
{
    public FormModuleMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
          .KeyReference(x => x.Form, "FormId")
          .KeyReference(x => x.Module, "ModuleId");

        Map(x => x.Sequence)
            .Column("SequenceNumber");

        //I've tried these
        //References(x => x.Module).Column(FormModuleTable.Column.FormId).Not.Nullable().Cascade.All();
        //References(x => x.Module).Column(FormModuleTable.Column.ModuleId).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Does anyone see why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score -1):

in general this complete code reads strange for me, but nethertheless

`public virtual Module Module { get; protected set; }`

How do you initiate the FormModule? Plz post some code you do this. Otherwise I'd say, if you do not set any`value to`Module`of`Formmodule`the value is null and so nhibernate tells you that it's`null or transient``

```
var formModule = new FormModule ();
formModule.Module = new Module(); //// this doesn't work with your code because of your protected setter
```

Imho your mapping is correct afais (besides that composite keys are never a good idea)

If you make the `module` having a public setter, it you should not get any errors with my code mentioned above